# How can I access an object's components from a different scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a Player gameObject that has a script on it which keeps some variables inside it. I created a scene which acts as a main menu and has "Shop" part in it, which has upgrades in it, basically I need to access Player gameObject's script from a different scene so I can modify variables from main menu scene. How can I do that ?

Comment: You can either save those variables from player in [playerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) or you can check [don't destroy on load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) . But playerPrefs might do better in your case

Comment: This has actually been asked quite many times. You have two approaches to consider, PlayerPrefs and DontDestroyOnLoad. I’d recommend the first. Static is often mentioned but this is not what static is meant to do, though it does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be default the components are instances of a class. If there isn't a GameObject with that component in the currently loaded scenes, there is nothing to access.
If I recall you can now load more than one scene at a time.

If there is a GameObject with that script currently loaded you can use:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html

or even better

use singleton design pattern, in case you have only 1 player at a time.

I guess you want to save these upgrades for the next run of the game, so you can use PlayerPrefs
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

If you want to save more than 50 values of data I would suggest using a file based DB like SQLite, it takes little time to setup and works very fast. And it is a lot more readable than using PlayerPrefs.

Comment: Thanks so much, I think I'll dig into singleton design patterns, loading more than a scene at a time to use the GameObject sounds pretty lazy, 2nd option sounds way better.

Answer (score 1):

check this out:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html

once your player is loaded this will keep him in every scene until you choose to release hiim, meaning when you load your menu scene he will be there to access.

now since we know hes there, we can:
(note that player is your script with the variables not your actual player)

```
ScriptName player = GameObject.FindObjectWithTag("yourtag").GetComponent<ScriptName>();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about static class?

You can keep values there and access it from any place you want :D